# create MAX k sublists out of n binary numbers of a list so that each sublist has as much matching bits as possible

Tags: list, algorithm, data-structures, binary, network-programming

As the title suggest, I'm trying to create an algorithm that takes in a list with length n and create <=k sublists so that each sublist has as much matching bits at same positions as possible. (each sublist should have the largest possible common prefix)

The binary numbers on the input always have 4bytes. You may view them as binary representation of ip addresses. Also keep in mind, that the binary numbers are already sorted.

Should be simple, but I just keep messing up

Examples:

```
k = 3
n = 6
binary_strings = [
    "00000000000000000011011000010000",
    "00000000001000000110000001100111",
    "00000000010110000110001111010111",
    "00000000010111010101010001010000",
    "00000011110111101101011111010000",
    "00000011111110000000111100001000",
]
```

The output for this input should be

```
00000011110111101101011111010000
00000011111110000000111100001000

00000000010111010101010001010000
00000000010110000110001111010111

00000000000000000011011000010000
00000000001000000110000001100111
```

```
k = 2
n = 4
binary_strings = [
    "00101010101010000000000000101010",
    "10000000000000010000000100000000",
    "11000000101010000000000100000000",
    "11000000110001001100010000000000",
]
```

Output for that example:

```
00101010101010000000000000101010

10000000000000010000000100000000
11000000101010000000000100000000
11000000110001001100010000000000
```

**EDIT:**

Each result sublist in this case is essentially a subnet with ip addresses in binary.

The goal is to create the biggest possible subnet mask that will fit all the subnets. In this environment, 1010 is a valid start of a mask as it can have interchangeable zeros and ones

Algorithm to create a subnet mask for the subnets:

```
    result_mask = ["." for _ in range(32)]
    for subnet in subnets:
        transposed = list(zip(*subnet))
        for j, match in enumerate(transposed):
            if len(set(match)) == 1:
                if result_mask[j] != "0":
                    result_mask[j] = "1"
            else:
                result_mask[j] = "0"

    result_mask = "".join(result_mask)
```

Comment: And your code attempts so far?

Comment: @Ripi2 I've tried to recursively add the binary values to sublists by checking if each byte (8bits) is somewhat different from the other ones, I would than group the binary values by matching bytes, but that didn't work for larger inputs and was reaaaally slow.

Comment: If you ask 10 developers you'll find 12 different code versions. Show yours, so any one may help you.

Comment: @Ripi2 I've scrapped that solution.. As I said it was garbage :( There should at least be some method that I can build upon. All I can think of is to brute force it with creating all combinations and then choosing the one that matches the wanted result the most, but that would be really inefficient

Comment: Starting from the leftmost bit, find the position of the first difference. Split the group into two groups. With multiple group find the split position of all of the groups, and split the group with the earliest split position. Keep splitting until the number of groups is equal to `k`.

Comment: This is a dynamic programming problem that can be solved with recursion and memoization. First define the cost of a division to be something like the sum over all inputs of `1/2^k` where `k` is the number of bits it shares with its group. Recursively solve for the lowest cost split into `k` groups. Memoize that solution. It should run in something like time `O(k*n^2)`.

Comment: @btilly could you please expand on this or maybe provide a code solution? I've never done dynamic programming to this point and am kinda lost.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually going to give a more efficient solution than I suggested before. Though write recursive function, then add caching layer to memoize will work.

This will be based on the idea of a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), which is implemented in Python's standard library by the [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) algorithm.

The idea is that we will have a heap of `(cost, partial_solution)` pairs. The idea is this:

```
while we have not reached the end:
    take the cheapest partial solution in the heap.
    if it reached the end:
        We have our answer!
    else if we have not reached this point before:
       mark that we've reached it to avoid redundant work on worse solutions.
       put extensions to this partial solution back in the heap.
```

This is actually a version of the [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) with a heuristic of `0`.

Here is code.

```
import heapq

def group_strings (k, binary_strings):
    # Sanity checks.
    if k < 1:
        if k == 0 and len(binary_strings) == 0:
            return []
        else:
            return None
    elif 0 == len(binary_strings):
        return []


    # Calculate the shared bits each shares with the next one.
    shared_bits = []
    for i in range(len(binary_strings) - 1):
        max_bits = min(len(binary_strings[i]), len(binary_strings[i+1]))
        shared_bits.append(max_bits)
        for j in range(max_bits):
            if binary_strings[i][j] != binary_strings[i+1][j]:
                shared_bits[i] = j
                break

    # A partial solution will look like:
    #
    #   (
    #     start index of last group,
    #     length of last group,
    #     shared bits of last group,
    #     number of groups,
    #     cost of all previous groups,
    #     (previous partial solution or none)
    #   )
    #
    # We can extend a partial solution in two ways.
    #
    # 1. Add one more to the current group.
    #
    # 2. Start a new group. We won't do this after k groups.

    # Start with the first partial solution that we will processed.
    heap = [(
        1/2**len(binary_strings[0]),
        (
            0,    # Start at beginning.
            1,    # 1 element
                  # Shares all of its bits with itself.
            len(binary_strings[0]),
            1,    # Only this group
            0,    # No cost of previous groups.
            None, # No previous group.
        )
    )]

    # We have so far processed nothing.
    seen = set()

    # We will return from inside of this loop when we find our answer.
    while True:
        # Get the cheapest partial solution.
        cost, partial = heapq.heappop(heap)

        # Break the partial solution into its fields.
        i, l, bits, groups, prev_cost, previous = partial

        # Did we reach the end?
        if i + l == len(binary_strings):
            # We just need to extract this solution in a nice form.
            answer = [binary_strings[i:i+l]]
            while previous is not None:
                i, l, bits, groups, prev_cost, previous = previous
                answer.append(binary_strings[i:i+l])

            # Return groups in the same order as binary_strings.
            return list(reversed(answer))

        # This will not lead to a better solution if we previously found
        # something that cost no more which:
        #
        #   - also included the first i+l binary_strings
        #   - with the same number of groups
        #   - the last group had the same number of bits.
        key = (i+l, groups, bits)

        if key not in seen:
            seen.add(key)
            # 1. Try adding one more to the last group.

            # Our last binary_string is at i+l-1.
            # Bits will be the smaller of the current value and
            # what that shares with the next binary string.
            next_bits = min(bits, shared_bits[i+l-1])
            heapq.heappush(
                heap,
                (
                    # The new cost is prev_cost + size/2^next_bits.
                    prev_cost + (l+1) / 2**next_bits,
                    # Mostly the same partial solution that we just had.
                    (
                        i,
                        l+1,        # The new group is one longer
                        next_bits,  # This is how many bits it shares
                        groups,
                        prev_cost,
                        previous,
                    )
                )
            )

            if groups < k:
                # We could instead start a new group of length 1 at i+l.
                heapq.heappush(
                    heap,
                    (
                        # cost is now the prev_cost.
                        cost + 1/2**len(binary_strings[i+l]),
                        (
                            i+l, # Starts where last group ended.
                            1,   # Only one element.
                                 # Shares all bits with itself.
                            len(binary_strings[i+l]),
                            groups + 1,
                            cost,
                            partial,
                        ),
                    )
                )
```

And here are your test cases.

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

pp.pprint(group_strings(3, [
    "00000000000000000011011000010000",
    "00000000001000000110000001100111",
    "00000000010110000110001111010111",
    "00000000010111010101010001010000",
    "00000011110111101101011111010000",
    "00000011111110000000111100001000"]))

pp.pprint(group_strings(2, [
   "00101010101010000000000000101010",
   "10000000000000010000000100000000",
   "11000000101010000000000100000000",
   "11000000110001001100010000000000",
]))
```

For me this gave:

```
[   ['00000000000000000011011000010000', '00000000001000000110000001100111'],
    ['00000000010110000110001111010111', '00000000010111010101010001010000'],
    ['00000011110111101101011111010000', '00000011111110000000111100001000']]
[   ['00101010101010000000000000101010'],
    [   '10000000000000010000000100000000',
        '11000000101010000000000100000000',
        '11000000110001001100010000000000']]
```

Which looks like exactly what you wanted.

Incidentally the whole idea of the partial solution pointing at a previous partial solution is something that I do a lot. It is based on the idea of a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), and usually does require a decoding step like the one that I did. But it has the benefit of not copying a ton of data for each partial solution.

---

The real question turned out to be much easier. Just keep cycling through groups, and splitting them on the next bit if you can until you have enough groups. You are always splitting the worst group, and wind up with a worst group that is as good as possible.

```
def split_binary_strings (binary_strings, k):
    max_depth = min((len(x) for x in binary_strings))

    # Our queue will be (i, j, depth) where:
    #
    #   - The group starts at i
    #   - The group ends at j-1
    #   - We are looking to split the group on the depth bit.
    #
    queue = [(0, len(binary_strings), 0)]
    while len(queue) < k and queue[0][2] < max_depth:
        i, j, depth = queue.pop(0)
        # Find where to find the first 1.
        lower = i
        upper = j
        while lower < upper:
            mid = (lower + upper)//2
            if binary_strings[mid][depth] == '0':
                lower = mid + 1
            else:
                upper = mid
        if i < lower:
            queue.append((i, lower, depth+1))
        if lower < j:
            queue.append((lower, j, depth+1))

    queue.sort()
    return [binary_strings[i:j] for i, j, depth in queue]
```

It can be tested similarly to before.

Comment: First of all, thanks a ton for the solution and the step by step comments <3 Helped me a lot. It works well for the example cases. Tho it doesn't work larger inputs, at least I have something that I can build upon.

Comment: @banan The issue is probably the score. I didn't know what you actually meant by "as much matching bits as possible" when we have a choice between matching more in one group and less in another. So I picked an easy to make tradeoff.

Comment: The binary strings represent ip addresses. There are 4 octets in every one of the binary string. The goal of this assignment was to subnet the ip addresses to maximum of k agroups(subnets), so the mask for the subnets (in this virtual "environment" we refer to mask as to a ip address that can have interchagable network/host parts, so a valid start of a subnet mask can be 1010) has the highest value possible.

The solution for the first example would then be:
 10111111000100100011101011111111 - 191.18.58.255
And for the second:
11111111110110000000000000000000 - 255.216.0.0

Comment: I understand that. But it still doesn't answer the question. Smaller groups match more bits. In the extreme, a subnet with one address is as good as possible. On what rule do we decide whether it is better to have a great group and a not so good group, versus two decent groups? The principle "more bits is better" doesn't answer that question. The score was my attempt to make an answer.

Comment: Yes, smaller groups usually can have more matching bits and a subnet with one address is possible if k allows it. Well the rule is to create the largest subnet mask possible that will be valid for all of the subnets. I've added a small algorithm to the problem description to calculate subnet mask from the subnets if that'll of any help. This assignment shouldn't be that hard to code, it's aimed for high schoolers. There should be some underlying math underneeth which I'm not able to see. BTW thx for putting up with me :)

Comment: @banan It looks like you want the worst group to be as good as possible. That has a much simpler solution!

Comment: @banan I added a solution for what looks to be your real problem. This is a much simpler problem, and indeed would be appropriate for high school students.

Comment: Why did I not think about it like that haha. Altho there seems to be some bug in the code you provided, yet again test cases work fine, but the large input data always ends on third iteration, where queue[0][0] becomes greater than max_depth

Comment: @banan. Oops, there was a bug in the line `while len(queue) < k and queue[0][0] < max_depth:`.  I need to look at where the depth of the head of the queue is, which is `queue[0][2]`. Fixed.

Comment: seems like we are still missing an edge-case, most of the big inputs still fail, one with n=578 and k=20 for example results in 11110000000000000000000000000000, but it should result in 11110101011111001110110101010000 It would be best if I sent you some of the large input cases, but it doesnt fit here on stackoverflow